# Where is redux store saved?

Tags: javascript, redux

I was looking into how secure a redux application can be, I am storing certain values in redux store i.e. user token etc.. and tried to see if someone else could gain access to them via an xss attack for example, I checked sessionStorage, localStorage, cookies and it is not there, as well as it is not inside my app.js file (my bundle file), hence my question.

Comment: A Redux store is just a JavaScript object. If you did `var store = {}`, you wouldn't expect to find it in persistent storage would you? It'll be defined somewhere in your app and stored in a heap in random-access memory.

Comment: @DanPrince Is it possible to access store in Chrome console when debugging a react-redux app?

Comment: Sure, either through [Redux Devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) or by making sure you add the store to the window object. Something like `let store = createStore(...); window.store = store`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From this part of documentation (http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#performance-state-memory) I deduce it's stored in memory, so it is not persistent.

Comment: does this mean that third party can gain access to redux store?

Comment: It's stored in browser's memory. Depends on your definition of 3rd party. Anything happened in client should be assumed accessible.

Comment: It is possible to access the store on the client side, but is it easy to do so? I am wondering if I can implement user auth use just Redux
for a small app supposed to be used internally in my company

Comment: @shintaroid - No no no.  At that point, you may as well forgo authentication entirely.  A whole host of client-side vulnerabilities make this far easier to exploit than you suspect. I would argue this is even more dangerous than no auth at all, since you are luring into a false sense of security.

Comment: @shintaroid - Sure thing! Sorry if I came across too harsh! I just really wanted to emphasize it.  Again, sorry if I came across meanly. Have a terrific day!

Comment: When you mean it is not persistent - does that mean after refreshing or closing browser or deleting cookie and history it is not saved?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid yes. You need to persist the redux using local storage or other kinds of persistent storage.

Answer (score 72):

Was just about to answer [How does React and Redux store data? Is it localstorage or cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695353/how-does-react-and-redux-store-data-is-it-localstorage-or-cookies) when it got closed as a duplicate. So I wanted to paste my answer here.

### Answer

First off, it's worth noting that UI libraries don't actually manage state (other than component-level state). ReactJS and VueJS expect you to pass data to them like you would pass parameters to a function. They aren't concerned with where this data came from or how you're storing it.

Redux, on the other hand, is **not** a UI library -- it's a state management library. Redux **does** store state. The VueJS corollary to Redux would be "Vuex".

With that out of the way, the next thing you need to know is that there's a difference between state **management** and state **persistence**. Libraries like Redux and Vuex usually keep track of your variables and provide tools for changing state (reducers, specifically) - but they don't manage the **persistence** of that state. Persistence refers to saving the state somewhere to reload it the next time someone comes to your app - and seems to be what you're curious about (since you mentioned cookies and Local Storage)

Persistence is usually coded by hand (send the state to an API endpoint which saves it to a database, then when you reload the page you ping a different API endpoint to retrieve the state) or you utilize a plugin / module for your state manager to handle persistence for you. For example, there's a popular Redux Local Storage plugin called (trivially enough) [redux-localstorage](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage)

Comment: You have a lot of interesting content around. May the upvotes and badges always be with you!

Comment: @stevendesu - Very nice, and crisp answer. Wish I could give more likes.

Answer (score 6):

The state in Redux is stored in memory. This means that, if you refresh the page the state gets wiped out. The state in redux is just a variable that persists in memory because it is referenced by all redux functions.

A misconception is:

> In redux, we know that the state is stored as an object.

This is not correct. State in redux can be any valid JavaScript value, not just an object. It just usually makes the most sense for it to be an object (or a special object like an array) because that allows for a more flexible data structure (but you could make the state just be a number for example, according to your need).

Answer (score 4):

Redux use internal memory for all data. For example, when you subscribe to Store, Redux just [push listener to private array](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L109) and do not use Cookies or LocalStorage.