# Storing JWT token in frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, backend

Im working on a fullstack application with Node and React. I used to store the JWT in redux, so I could send it as a header with every request which should be authenticated. But recently I saw a video that said storing our JWT in redux/flux/mobx is vulnerable. ***How can this be vulnerable?*** The alternative approach he suggested was to send a cookie from the backend to the frontend with the token. So that it can be stored in the browser cookies. That way we don't have to send the token with every request.

Which approach is better here? What are the vulnerabilities of storing the token on redux?

Comment: Afaik, redux works in memory and memory is cleared when you close the website, does not seem vunerable to me. However, for jwtokens, i personally would use sessionstorage and if they want to stay logged in, localstorage. Seems perfectly fine.

Comment: It is vulnerable to XSS attack because redux stores state just like localstorage. Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329193/where-is-redux-store-saved

Comment: This will give you some context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258744/1235935

Comment: localstorage is safer than cookies https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Notes

Comment: @Zoidbergseasharp localstorage is never safe unless a fingerprint is also used in the form of a cookie, and cookie is never safe unless measures are taken to protect it from XSS & CSRF. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258744/1235935

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Storing your JWT token in the redux store does not make it vulnerable. You should store it in localStorage, which is a secure and persistent way of storing user tokens.

If you store them in redux or sessionStorage, the token will dissapear after a page reload, but this is in no way considered insecure.

Comment: Using `localStorage` is not secure. You can check OWASP's recommendations: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md#local-storage