# ReactJS: How to make redux store inaccessible outside the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How can I make the redux store inaccessible outside of react?
Is there any way I can store a value in a private variable throughout the session?

Comment: For example, you can create a react hook or some factory, which will store your variable inside app, and then just import/export it when needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329193/where-is-redux-store-saved

Comment: @demkovych can  react hook or some factory also be accessible  from outside react ?

Comment: No, they are living only inside react app.

Comment: Or you can encrypt your value and store it in browser session storage

Comment: but anyway, your client-side code and variables are viewable to all.

Comment: Inacessible to who? To other parts of your application? To other scripts on the same page? To the person using the browser?

Comment: @ivarni  to other scripts

Comment: Redux store is only available through "getStore" api or exposed on middlewares. Unless you are exposing store to outside scripts, it shouldn't be accessible to any script. Redux logger accesses it through middleware.

Answer (score 2):

store is available only with react component that are connected with the store using connect() hoc and if super parent component in the app wrapped into provider.
no other react component can access the store.

Comment: Actually you declare the store in global scope before you pass it to the root store wrapper so even though you're not supposed to you could import the store into any component or even plain JS function and do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 2):

Truly inaccessible isn't really possible in Javascript. Code can be minified and obfuscated but ultimately it is all available, however hard to read.

There is an article about hooking up Twitter's redux store to the redux dev tools here. https://medium.com/statuscode/dissecting-twitters-redux-store-d7280b62c6b1

Answer (score 2):

Store is a single source of truth and whatever set there will be available in the scope of parent  component but you can restrict to access store data by hooks as below:

Initialize store:

```
const initialState = {
  user: null,
  permissions: [],
  isAuthenticating: false,
  authError: null,
}
```

Reducer function:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'AUTH_BEGIN':
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticating: true,
      }

    case 'AUTH_SUCCESS':
      return {
        isAuthenticating: false,
        user: action.user,
        permissions: action.permissions
        authError: null,
      }

    case 'AUTH_FAILURE':
      return {
        isAuthenticating: false,
        user: null,
        permissions: []
        authError: action.error,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

App Component:

```
function App() {
  const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(initialState)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar user={store.user} />
      <LoginPage store={store} dispatch={dispatch} />
      <Dashboard />
      <SettingsPage permissions={store.permissions} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Here you can see store is optional to pass in particular component in above example  component can not access store.